# How should I transport my big LEGO sets?

Tags: storage

I'm moving and I have some big LEGO sets (Police Station, Fire Station, and Ultra Stealth Raider).  How should I pack them so they won't get shattered to pieces in transit?

Answer (score 1):

You should disassemble the buildings to smaller parts, then pack these parts with bubble foils. After that, you can place them in massive plastic boxes. LEGO bricks aren't really fragile.